# Rails simple form routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes

I have a form in Rails

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h3>Create Blah</h3>
</div>
<%= simple_form_for @blah do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :id %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :pho %>
    <%= f.input :fun %>
    <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
<br>
```

When I click the submit button, where does the code attempt to go? Does it call the create method for `blah_controller.rb`? Because currently, I get a routing error

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant BlahsController
```

Here is the `BlahController#create` method:

```
 def create
    authorize! :create, :blahs
    @blah = Blah.new(params[:blah])
    if @blah.save
      redirect_to admin_blah_path(@blah), :notice => 'New blah created!'
    else
      render :new
    end
 end
```

In my `rake routes`, I have

```
    admin_blahs GET    /admin/blahs(.:format)                      admin/blahs#index
                POST   /admin/blahs(.:format)                      admin/blahs#create
 new_admin_blah GET    /admin/blahs/new(.:format)                  admin/blahs#new
edit_admin_blah GET    /admin/blahs/:id/edit(.:format)             admin/blahs#edit
     admin_blah GET    /admin/blahs/:id(.:format)                  admin/blahs#show
                PUT    /admin/blahs/:id(.:format)                  admin/blahs#update
                DELETE /admin/blahs/:id(.:format)                  admin/blahs#destroy
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the controller method where you create (at)blah before the form is rendered?  Also, there is a typo in the line if (at)bla.save, should be (at)blah.save  [replace (at) with @]

Comment: the typo happened when I was typing the question...sorry.

Comment: @elevine it's just (at)blah = Blah.new

Comment: Have you inspected the html to see what the forms `action` attribute is (ie. the URI it's getting passed to)?

Comment: No, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you give more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `BlahsController` is a namespaced controller, living under the `Admin` module (i.e., its fully-qualified name is `Admin::BlahsController`). If so, when constructing forms you must also provide the `:admin` namespace, using something like the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @blah] do |f| %>
```

See the [Rails Guide to Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification), under the **"Dealing with Namespaces"** section.